# What's the name of a symlink that creates a loop

Tags: symlink

I.e. what is the name of a symlink that points to either:

- the directory the link itself is in
- the parent directory
- some other "super-directory"

Personally I call them backlinks but I would like to know if there is like a common name for them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it “recursive”.

In a stricter sense, though, only a symlink referring to itself might be considered truly “recursive”.